# How Can We Clarify What "Community Wiki" Means?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow)

After finding zero reliable and working information on iptables and egress rules on the first page of Google, I did a bunch of research and thought ServerFault would be a great place to store this information to save other people time.

I initially posted this as a Community Wiki, then was yelled at, so I reposted it as a question and answer...and got downvoted for it by people that misunderstood the concept of "community wiki" as I did.

**What can we do to clarify what Community Wiki means?**

I was thinking that maybe we should put a little question mark next to it and say that it is for "subjective" posts only. Or perhaps we should change the name to "completely subjective"?

Comment: I don't see it as an exact duplicate. There is a difference between "What is a Community Wiki post" and "How Can we Clarify It". One is informational, the other might lead to good feature requests. Please re-open.

Comment: please provide links to your actual question, since this is about [specific-question] really.

Comment: That would be: http://serverfault.com/questions/60366/how-do-you-setup-egress-rules-with-iptables-on-ubuntu